# Stack Exchange Podcast download file name is wrong and id3 tags are missing

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, podcast

After navigating to a stack exchange podcast post e.g. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-05/ and clicking on the download link e.g. http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/15494022-stack-exchange-sta.mp3 the resulting redirect downloads a file with a strange name e.g. **wbgXWhv5cS3K.128.mp3**

All of the ID3 tags for Title, Album, Genre etc are also missing from the downloaded file. Is this a system problem with the Podtrac service or am I the only person experiencing this problem?

I do not have this problem with any other podcasts I am downloading. I have tried downloading the file directly in Firefox, Chrome and IE9 as well as using Firefox DownloadthemAll extension and the problem exists in all cases.

Comment: problem with strange file names has been already raised in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89052/could-you-give-the-podcast-files-more-appropriate-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be fixed with the update to our distribution system.

Comment: Just downloaded SE Podcast #19 and the all looks good, thanks.